# Display customer transaction frequency within the last X days

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column to display the number of transactions each customer has had in the last X days, updated with each new transaction. Let X = 1.

I have the columns Customer_ID and TransactionDate. I want to create column "HowManyTransactionsInLast1Day".

Something like this is what I want:

```
Customer_ID  TransactionDate    HowManyTransactionsInLast1Day
A        2021-03-03             0
B        2021-05-10             0
B        2022-09-06             0
C        2010-09-10             0
D        2009-05-24             0
D        2009-05-25             1
D        2009-05-25             2
D        2009-05-26             2
D        2009-08-14             0
D        2009-08-14             1
```

I was able to find a solution using pandas .rolling that seems to do the trick, but it's way too slow with the 5M+ rows I'm working with. Here's what I have:

```
delta = 1
df['%sDTransactionCount_Cust' %(delta)] = df.assign(count=1).groupby(['Customer_ID']).apply(lambda x: x.rolling('%sD' %delta, on='TransactionDate').sum())['count'].astype(int)-1
```

Is there a faster, clean way to do this? Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the apply makes it look cleaner to me.  I think it will be a little faster as well:

```
data = '''
Customer_ID,TransactionDate
A,2021-03-03
B,2021-05-10
B,2022-09-06
C,2010-09-10
D,2009-05-24
D,2009-05-25
D,2009-05-25
D,2009-05-26
D,2009-08-14
D,2009-08-14
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['TransactionDate'])

df.assign(HowManyTransactionsInLast1Day=1) \
    .groupby('Customer_ID') \
    .rolling('1D', on='TransactionDate', closed='both')['HowManyTransactionsInLast1Day'] \
    .sum() - 1

Customer_ID  TransactionDate
A            2021-03-03         0.0
B            2021-05-10         0.0
             2022-09-06         0.0
C            2010-09-10         0.0
D            2009-05-24         0.0
             2009-05-25         1.0
             2009-05-25         2.0
             2009-05-26         2.0
             2009-08-14         0.0
             2009-08-14         1.0
Name: HowManyTransactionsInLast1Day, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Much faster, thank you!